# when dialog result for form get return

Tags: winforms, forms, dialogresult

hi i have on object (serverconnection from sqlserver Managament object ) i need send this object to other form to configure connection option and  connect so object return  but when i send this object to form2 how return it  or when i use form.ShowDialog() when this return or how return from this

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a property into your second form, e.g.:

```
if( form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
{
    var configuration = form2.Configuration;
}
```

here the property is called `Configuration` and holds the object you need.